# Video Upload to the Facebook from local drive

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, python-requests

I am trying to upload videos from local drive but some what it is not uploading the file through request post of python

```
import requests
import json

accesstoken = '-----------------'
desc = 'This is test'
titl = 'Testing Video'
vidfbpath = '/tempvideos/0xjwseCVUlU.mp4'
source = open(vidfbpath, 'rb')

 # need binary rep of this, not sure if this would do it
 fburl = 'https://graph-video.facebook.com/v2.0/1098719680172720/videos?access_token='+str(accesstoken) 
 # put it all together to post to facebook
 m = {'description': desc,
        'title': titl,
        'source': vidfbpath,}

 r = requests.post(fburl, data=m).text
 fb_res = json.loads(r)
```

The output is returning InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning

Comment: Did you try the suggestions contained in the reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`InsecurePlatformWarning` is a warning, not an error. There is still a good chance that you can successfully upload your video files.

As it is, your code will send a POST HTTP request with a Content-Type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`,  and it will encode the form data appropriately. This does *not* actually upload the file, it just posts the location of the file in the `source` form variable.

I think that you need to upload the file using a content type of `multipart/form-data` as [described](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) here. It would also be a good idea to specify the content type of the mp4 file. Something like this:

```
m = {'description': desc,
      'title': titl,}

files = {'source': ('0xjwseCVUlU.mp4', open('/tempvideos/0xjwseCVUlU.mp4', 'rb'), 'video/mp4')}

r = requests.post(fburl, data=m, files=files)
```